# Android - Detect app moving to background and foreground

Tags: java, android

If application is gone to background and come back after 5 minutes, I need to restart the app.
We can leave the restart part, how will we detect the app moving to background and to foreground? Please help.

If there is a link on details of its official impossibility or possibility, please share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when it moves to the background it does `onPause()` and when it resumes it does `onResume()`, see the activity lifecycle.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: Bill is correct.  Too many people just don't seem to quite "get" the way an application in Android works.  It's not a traditional scheme.  Your app cannot really be considered running except when a section of code is currently being executed.  Any other time it may or may not exist, and Android will save the state and may or may not ever start your code again.  Activity Lifecycle is one thing everyone should read 10 times or more and then write a test app with all the On[Whatever] events to see exactly when things happen.

Comment: onPause() is also fired when you go to another activity. And onResume() when you return to that activity.

Comment: onResume doesn't work well. I tried it and sometimes the onResume is called while the phone is locked. After investigating, I found that in the definition of the onResume in the documentation, it says:
Keep in mind that onResume is not the best indicator that your activity is visible to the user; a system window such as the keyguard may be in front. Use onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) to know for certain that your activity is visible to the user (for example, to resume a game).http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29

Answer (score 1):

Override **onStop()** in each Activity. This method will be called when activity goes in background. Then note the time.

Override **onStart()**. This will be called when activity moves from background to foreground. Then note the time here.

Comment: I think you mean onResume() and onPause(). onStop() and onStart() is used when you completely close the application and when you boot it up when it was completely shut down. onResume() and onPause() is used when the application was running in/is send to the background. Pressing the home button will move it to the background (`onPause()`), pressing the back button will close it (`onStop()`)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where every time the app returned from background Fragment B kept recalculating results based on the output from Fragment A in the activity (where Fragment A sends data to Fragment B based on user input). The following solution uses a simple Boolean check and should work for most purposes. This allowed me to keep the old FragmentB results even after a long time away from the app (assuming the results in FragmentB aren't so memory-hungry that Android cleans them after some time).

```
//Code from Fragment B
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    Boolean app_was_in_background;
    @Override public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        app_was_in_background = true;
    }
    @Override public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            String output_to_FragmentB = getArguments().getString("input_from_FragmentA");

            if (app_was_in_background == null || !app_was_in_background) {
                app_was_in_background = false;

                PerformMyAlgorithm(output_to_FragmentB);
            }
        }
    }
    public void PerformMyAlgorithm(String input) {
        //Code that includes Spinners and calculations, where I want to app
        //to return to the user's chosen spinner location and display
        //results as the user saw them before switching to another app
        //on the device. All this without explicitly "saving" the Spinner 
        //position and data in memory.
    }
}
```

As a side note, applying the same logic to onStart() *instead* of onResume() can lead to unwanted results:

PerformMyAlgorithm receives the FragmentA output (ie. String output_to_FragmentB) again *automatically* at onResume() *without* the user choosing to to so by clicking a Button in FragmentA (my guess is that this due to the way Android manages Fragment lifecycles).

I don't want this since when returning from background (ie. onResume) the FragmentB Views and calculations are reset and redisplayed/recalculated instead of immediately showing the user the results prior to sending the app to background (ie. onPause).